# How to disable device Automatic Time Zone value programmatically using Reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am creating a System Application where i want to enable disable Automatic Time Zone value of the device.

This code doesn't work as we need root permission to change system settings.

```
Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME_ZONE, isAutomatic ? 0 : 1);
```

I have rooted device also but no success, after searching a lot found that it will be possible using Reflection. Anybody knows how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution by placing the apk in system/priv-app instead of system/app.

Reflection is used to access the private members or classes,the Settings.Global is not private api but need security permission which is solved by placing the apk in system/priv-app folder instead of system/app.

Following code worked if the device is rooted and apk is in path priv-app

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME_ZONE, isAutomatic ? 0 : 1);
            } else {
                android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME_ZONE, isAutomatic ? 0 : 1);
            }
```

Comment: It works as expected, however set the automatic setting to false (0) when the variable `isAutomatic` is true is a bit missleading.